# How to safely extract nested values from YAML file using SnakeYaml?

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I am working on extracting values from YAML Files in Java using the Snakeyaml library. Unfortunately, I am having a hard time extracting values from these files when I do not know the contents of the file in advance.

As such I am looking for a safe why to extract nested values from a given YAML File.

Here my approach:

```java
Map<String, Object> dataMap = yaml.load(FileUtils.readFileToString(file, StrandardCharsets.UTF_8));
for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: dataMap.entrySet()) {
    if(entry.getValue() instanceof Map<String, Object>) {
        // Do something. Potentially loop again, because I do not know the depth of the File
    } else {
        // Get actual Value
    }
}
```

Comment: At the heart of it, most markup languages consist of either Map (Blocks in YAML) or List (Series in YAML). The `String` will be the key for each section (block or series), and the `Object` will either be a `Map`, `List`, or some scalar value (`String`, `Integer`, etc). A `Map` should always have a `String` key, and you'll have to check the values each time if you don't know what they are. That said, consider the fact that by parsing+loading the file, you've already "determined" the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function that recursively reads all the fields in the yml file.
I have not tested it thoroughly, but I would say that it works as expected.

```
 public static void readMapRec(Map<String,Object> map){
        if(Objects.isNull(map) || map.entrySet().size()==0){
            return;
        }
        for(Map.Entry<String,Object> entry: map.entrySet()){
            try {
                if (entry.getValue() instanceof List) {
                    for(int i = 0 ; i< ((List<?>) entry.getValue()).size();i++) {
                        Map<String, Object> casted = (Map<String, Object>) ((List<?>) entry.getValue()).get(i);
                        readMapRec(casted);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey() +" "+entry.getValue());
                }
            }catch (Exception ex){
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("myFile.yml"));

        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        Map<String, Object> data = yaml.load(inputStream);

        readYml(data);

    }
```

So, If you have yml file like this:

```
id: 20
name: Bruce
year: 2020
address: Gotham City
department: Computer Science
courses:
  - name: Algorithms
    credits: 6
  - name: Data Structures
    credits: 5
  - name: Design Patterns
    credits: 3
books:
  - ds:
      - a: test
      - b: test
      - c:
          - e: test
          - f: test
```

You should see output like this:

```
id 20
name Bruce
year 2020
address Gotham City
department Computer Science
name Algorithms
credits 6
name Data Structures
credits 5
name Design Patterns
credits 3
a test
b test
e test
f test
```

Comment: It seems pretty solid however when running through the list of courses it reads it separately, whereas they are one if I am reading this correctly. My output: `Is list for: courses
{name=Algorithms, credits=6}
Putting Key: [courses, name] with Value: Algorithms
Putting Key: [courses, credits] with Value: 6
{name=Data Structures, credits=5}
Putting Key: [courses, name] with Value: Data Structures
Putting Key: [courses, credits] with Value: 5
{name=Design Patterns, credits=3}
Putting Key: [courses, name] with Value: Design Patterns
Putting Key: [courses, credits] with Value: 3`

Comment: The issue would be that a call to Courses -> credits would result in 3 possible answers. Is this an issue with the code, or with the formatting of the YAML file?

Comment: These are separate courses. It should read them separately. Basically, it's a list of key-value pairs  (maps) . Where each key-value is separate course. So for the provided yml example I would say that the output is correct

Answer (score 0):

I slightly adapted the function you proposed up top to catch indiscriminate cases:

```java
private @NotNull Map<String[], Object> parseMap(@NotNull Map<String, Object> map, String[] previousRoot) {
            Map<String[], Object> values = new HashMap<>();
            if(map.entrySet().size()==0){
                return values;
            }
            for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: map.entrySet()){
                try {
                    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(previousRoot));
                    list.add(entry.getKey());
                    String[] key = list.toArray(previousRoot);
                    if (entry.getValue() instanceof List) {
                        List<Map<String, Object>> objectItems = new ArrayList<>();
                        for(int i = 0 ; i< ((List<?>) entry.getValue()).size();i++) {
                            Map<String, Object> casted = (Map<String, Object>) ((List<?>) entry.getValue()).get(i);
                            if(casted.size() > 1) {
                                objectItems.add(casted);
                            } else {
                                values.putAll(parseMap(casted, key));
                            }
                        }
                        if(!objectItems.isEmpty()) {
                            System.out.println("Putting Key: " + Arrays.toString(key) + " with Value: " + objectItems);
                            values.put(key, objectItems);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Putting Key: " + Arrays.toString(key) + " with Value: " + entry.getValue());
                        values.put(key, entry.getValue());
                    }
                }catch (Exception ex){
                    System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return values;
        }
```

What do you think?
If you have any suggestions as to how it could be refined, I would be happy to hear them. :)

Comment: Not sure what are indiscriminate cases,but function that I wrote will display every key value pair and as far as I understand that was the essence of this question.